# How to use an if statement with match expresion in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have the following groovy code where `/data/JarFiles/` contain many `.jar` files and `/data/XML/Platform/` contain some `xml` files used to launch the jar:

```
Jar=[]
path = "/data/JarFiles"
new File(path).eachFileMatch(~/.*.jar/) {
      Jar.add(it)
}  


return Jar.sort{it.lastModified()}.collect{it.name}.reverse()

if (Jar.equals("Core2_v4.1.6.jar") && Product.equals("maximus")) {
  Platform=[]
path2 = "/data/XML/Platform/"
new File(path2).eachFileMatch(~/.*K6_Platform.*/) {
      Platform.add(it.getName())
}  
return Platform.sort()
```

I want to do something like this:

```
...
    if (Jar.Match(~/.*Core2_v4.*/) && Product.equals("maximus")) {
...
```

Can somebody help me with this please?
Thank you!

Comment: what do you expect from this code: `Jar.eachFileMatch(~/.*Core2_v4.*/)` ?

Comment: Yes, I know, this is a wrong code example but how I can replace this with something logic... I need something like this:if(Jar match expression){

Comment: but `Jar` in your case is an array of names. should they all match or at least one?

Comment: At least one...

Comment: `if ( Jar.find{it~=/.*Core2_v4.*/}  && Product.equals("maximus"))`

Comment: This error I get:startup failed:
Script1: 8: expecting '}', found '~'

Comment: oh. it should be `=~` instead of `~=`. if ( Jar.find{it=~/.*Core2_v4.*/} && Product.equals("maximus"))

Comment: Not working ,I think the conditions is always false even if I have two jars with name:Core2_v4.1.jar and Core2_v4.2.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the sample that works fine

```
def Jar = ['sdfgsdfg', 'Core2_v4.1.jar', 'aaa', 'bbb']
def Product = "maximus"

if( Jar.find{it=~/Core2_v4/} && Product=="maximus" ){
    println "OK"
}else{
    println "Failed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works perfectly for me is:

```
Jar=[]
path = "/data/JarFiles"
new File(path).eachFileMatch(~/.*.jar/) {
      Jar.add(it)
}  

return Jar.sort{it.lastModified()}.collect{it.name}.reverse()

if (Jar=~/Core2_v4/) && Product.equals("maximus")) {
  Platform=[]
path2 = "/data/XML/Platform/"
new File(path2).eachFileMatch(~/.*K6_Platform.*/) {
      Platform.add(it.getName())
}  
return Platform.sort()
```